# nutanix Acropolis How attach a disk to Vm using UUID

Tags: virtual-machine, acropolis

I have attached a disk to `vm` using Acopolis command

```
 acli vm.disk_create Vm  clone_from_nfs_file=filepath.raw bus=scsi
```

and write data to this disk using `dd`  and detach a disk.

If  I attach a disk again I am unable to see the written data to disk.

Please help me solve this problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a `vmdisk` in this way, you're creating a copy-on-write clone of the original file. All writes go to the clone, not the original file. If you want to access the cloned file, it is located on NFS here:

- /**$container_name**/.acropolis/vmdisk/**$vmdisk_uuid**

You can determine the container ID and `vmdisk` UUID by looking at the vm descriptor using the `vm.get` command.